# Как сделать подачу сигнала на сервер через сокет? Подарив клиенту пульт управления

Tags: python, сокет, сокеты

[image: По нажатию кнопки подаётся сигнал на сервер main.py]

Есть два кода на питоне - main и client.
Один для сервера, другой для клиента(с данной кнопкой).
Как сделать постоянную подачу сигнала по нажатию кнопки?

[image: main.py]
[image: client.py]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: постоянную это значит с переодичностью слать одно и тоже?

Comment: Ну чтобы сигнал был послан на сервер и его можно было послать повторно, чтобы опр. действие выполнилось на сервере ещё раз. В моём коде же действие выполняется лишь один раз после нажатия кнопки у клиента.